# Reason of dividing to n! ( repetition ) on Permutations with Repetitions

Tags: permutations, factorial

I'm trying to figure out the reason of diving the number of permutations by the number of repetitions (in factorial). Shouldn't it be without the factorial? I don't get why are there is a factorial in the denominator. For instance in the problem:

> How many anagram are there of the word "AMANHECE" ( portuguese )?

we have the solution:

$$\frac{8!}{2!2!}$$

but shouldn't it be:

$$\frac{8!}{2\cdot2}$$

-why do we get $2!$ instead of $2$?

Comment: $2!=2$.  One possible reason to write it this way:  if there were $3$ A's, say, then you'd have $3!$ in the denominator.

Comment: but in the case of 3 repetitions would be 3! that is different of 3, don't it ?

Comment: Yes, and $3!$ would be correct.  If $a,b,c$ are all different then there are $3!=6$ ways to permute them.  If they are all the same, then there is only $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, the factorials don't really matter because $2!=2$, but in general, we do need to take factorials. Consider a simpler problem: How many anagrams does the word "AAAB" have? The answer is clearly $4$, since once we know where the "B" is, we know the rest of the letters are "A". To get there, we have to consider that there are $4!=24$ ways to arrange $4$ distinguishable letters. However, since there are $3$ of the letter "A", we can rearrange the "A"s in $3!$ ways without changing the word (e.g. swapping the first and third letters in "AAAB" has no effect). Thus, there are $\frac{4!}{3!}=4$ anagrams of "AAAB".

This is to say that the division represents accounting for a set of letters that can be freely rearranged - and we need to divide out the number "useless" rearrangements that we have. Factorials take in the size of a set a spit out how many ways we could rearrange it - so we get them both in numerator (total number of rearrangements) and denominator (number of useless rearrangements)

Comment: Thanks milo, just try to demostrate it here, its seems that there are 6 ways for the A place on this 3 spaces as you said, but what about if the B is on the frist space like: AAAB ( 6 forms useless) BAAA ( another 6 forms useless ), i know the mathod and use it but the concept is really not solid yet

Comment: @MateusN. The important thing is that, no matter where the $B$ goes there will be $6$ useless forms - you can always rearrange the $A$'s in $6$ ways without changing the word. To put it another way, for each anagram, there are $6$ permutations yielding the same word (i.e. the useless forms). There are $24$ permutations - so the number $n$ of anagrams satisfies $6n=24$ - i.e. $n=\frac{24}6$.

Comment: Ohhh i got it, it's really make so much sense now, thank you so much Milo, was a basic question but important for my study!